# how to select a table by label of th with jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to select a specific row of a table to hide it with jquery. i am trying to combine the selector with the .find() child selector. here is the structure of the table:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tbody><tr>
<th><label for="email">email</th>
<td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="regular-text">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th><label for="url">url</label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" class="regular-text code"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th><label for="aim">AIM</label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="aim" id="aim" value="" class="regular-text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

what i am going to do is first choose the table and make all the rows with display:none :

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').find().css('display', 'none');//here i got stuck with finding the right form
```

and the making only the right row appear(in my case i need the email)

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').find().first-child().css('display', 'block');
```

it needs some polishing but my main concern is the find section.
any ideas?

EDIT: i forgot to write i have several tables with the same class and i need to pick the right one. according to the for attribute in the label.

Comment: What do you mean "the right row"?

Comment: @Itay i mean that i have several rows in my table and i need to hide all of them but the first. but my main problem i choosing the right table, i edited the title of the question now

Comment: @Itay, sorry, misunderstood - thought nearly the opposit, deleted answer

Comment: This is still the same table. Do you want to find the table row that shall not be deleted according to the for attribute?

Comment: I edited my answer to cover multiple tables -- I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it, but it works.

Comment: well i guess you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `find()` -- to hide all you can just do:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').css('display', 'none');
```

Or

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').hide();
```

To show the first you can use:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').first().show();
```

**EDIT**

And, to show a given row you can do:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr td input[name="aim"]').parent().parent().show();
```

Which is a little clunky, and prone to breaking, but it should work -- it would be better if you could give ids to the `tr` elements.

**EDIT 2** In response to your edit ...

You can hide a table with a given element (id = `aim`) like this:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr td input#aim').parent().parent().parent().children().hide();
```

and then show a single row (id = `aim`) like this:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr td input#aim').parent().parent().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide elements you can use the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function.

And you were misusing the `.find()` function. It's advisable that you read its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

The following code selects all the table rows and filters out the first one, then hide the remaining rows (second and beyond).

```
$('.form-table > tbody > tr').not(':first-child').hide();
```

Comment: hi, i need the find to get the right table. i edited the question, i have several tables and i have to choose the right one according to the first tr label.

Comment: is there a way to choose lets say the second table?

Comment: Your question shows only one table... Maybe show us something more similar to your real DOM so we will understand you better

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all of the rows like this:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').hide();
```

if your email field will be the first row, you can show it like this:

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').first().show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLeMG/

If you want a specific table, you should just give your tables ids, and use the id selector, it's gonna be easier for you that way.

Comment: hi, unfortunatlly i cant give every table its own id otherwise i wouldnt ask the question.

Comment: @Anton.P if all tables have the same exact information, the only way you can access them separately is by using some type of index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.form-table tbody tr').gt(1).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Itay answer. jQuery has show and hide to handle elements. Otherwise Try:

```
$('.form-table tbody').find('tr').css('display', 'none'); //which hides all rows in table
$('.form-table tbody').find('tr:first-child').css('display', 'block'); //which will show first row in table
```

Comment: @Itay updated. We can use show and hide If user would like to go with css then we can use the above mentioned code :)